# How can I write a certain number of characters from a file to a string?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am new to c++ and would like to know how I could select a certain number of characters from a file using fstream and write it into a string in c++?

```
 fstream ifile;
 ifile.open("file.txt" ios::out);
 ifile << "1234567890";
 ifile.close();
```

And then somehow be able to open the file select "567" and write it into a string buffer. Thanks

`

Comment: How are you selecting "567"?  Are you just looking for the 3 characters starting at the character in position 5?  Or are you looking for 3 characters that follow the character "4"?  Or what?  Some more clarity would be helpful.

Comment: I would like to open this file start at position 4 and get the 3 characters from that point which would be "567" and store that in a string. I don't know how to select "567" that's why I'm asking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want 3 characters from the open file stream, starting at index 4:

```
char ra[7];
if (ifile.read(7)) {
    std::string result(ra+4, ra+7);
} else {
    // read failed
}
```

If the starting index were significantly bigger than `4` then you might consider `seekg` or `ignore`, to skip over the unwanted characters instead of reading them into your buffer.

Comment: ok Thank you. Would you happen to know how exactly I could implement seekg to a bigger starting index?

Comment: @user2805625: there are hundreds (possibly thousands) of functions in the C++ standard library. You can't ask someone how to call each one, you need to look it up. For example, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatted input to a `std::string` to read at most a certain number of `char`. This doesn't mean, however, that as many characters are, indeed, read because the input stops when the specified number of characters is reached:

```
std::string str;
if (std::cin >> std::setw(3) >> str) {
    std::cout << "read '" << str << "'\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed to read string\n";
}
```

Of course, breaking off at spaces may be a bit annoying. It is possible, of course, to redefine the meaning of whitespace for streams using a custom `std::ctype<char>` facet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

struct ctype
    : std::ctype<char>
{
    ctype()
        : std::ctype<char>(table)
    {
    }
    std::ctype_base::mask table[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
};

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new ctype));
    if (std::cin >> std::setw(30) >> str) {
        std::cout << "read '" << str << "'\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed to read string\n";
    }
}
```